# Reference .NET Framework from online

Tags: .net, reference, cloud

Is there a way to refrence .NET framework from online, so those who do not have .NET framework installed on their system can still run the application as the dll files are online.

This is a bit like the cloud

Thanks.

Comment: The way to fix this is to include a .Net Framework bootstrapper in your application installer that can manage downloading and installing the appropriate framework if it does not exist on the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You cannot run a .Net application without the .Net JITter and GAC installed locally.

However, you can load other 3rd-party assemblies from the internet by handling the `AssemblyResolve` event.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

The assembly loader is not "cloud" aware nor are the runtime and other parts.

And even if there was a way, do you really want applications that would stop working as soon as you went offline?